# How to right align text in a DataGrid column header in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, header, alignment

I have a WPF DataGrid with a column header as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Length" Width="100">
     ...
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How do I make this header align right? Thanks. I know how to align the column content. Emphasis is aligning COLUMN HEADER.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the header using the `HeaderStyle`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out this will not produce "right align text" as per question title, but rather _right_ aligned `TextBlock` (with _left_ aligned text).

Answer (score 7):

H.B's answer is correct; just add one more line:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit plz?