# Is there a way to style the unwanted rightmost column in Wpf Datagrid so that it looks different from rest of the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using Wpf DataGrid and I can see a last unwanted column, which I understand is just a filler for the available space on the right, and is not an actual column as such. Is there a way to style that column a bit different than rest of the grid so that I can highlight that it is not an actual column?

Comment: Try this if you wish to remove that column. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215068/removing-datagrid-blank-column/18216111#18216111

Answer (score 0):

Apply a style to targettype header with a trigger that does whatever you want when content equals {x:null}. Since the last header has no content the trigger will fire on that one.